# Add to array as value, not reference

Tags: unreal-engine4

Trying to add a class to an array. The class contain an object and an integer. However, when I destroy the SELF the class reference in the array is removed as well? How do I add by value?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UObjects` are inherently a reference semantics entity. Their lifetime and memory management is controlled by the engine.

It sounds like `HerbType` should be a class reference, which you would spawn when necessary.